# How can I close an application window after it's been idle X minutes?

Tags: windows, autohotkey, idle

I use Remote Desktop Manager daily to log into my Macbook Pro from my Windows PC (Windows 10).  But once connected via ARD, it stays logged in basically forever.  I would like to have the connection window close itself automatically after an idle period, maybe 10-15 minutes.

I'm guessing I could probably script this with AutoHotKey or similar, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this using only built-in tools of Windows, maybe a batch script, etc.?  I would love some suggestions on how to accomplish this.  I'm not opposed to dedicated apps as well, but to be clear, I don't want to quit the application, just close the single connection window.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this AutoHotKey script:

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v1.1

#Persistent  ; keeps the script permanently running

SetTimer, close_connection_window, 60000 ; 1 minute timer
return

    close_connection_window:
If WinExist("title of the connection window") 
    time++ ; checks the number in the variable "time" and increases it by 1 every 1 minute (in accordance with the timer period)
else
    time := 0     ; reset
If (time = 15)    ; 15 minutes
{
    WinClose, title of the connection window
    time := 0     ; reset
}
return
```

Replace `title of the connection window` with the title of the window you want to close.

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm

Comment: Thanks, I'm hoping to avoid AHK if possible but will keep this in mind if all else fails.

Comment: If you have a [permanetly running AHK script](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/FAQ.htm#Startup) with hotkeys/hotstrings and/or other functions you can add the above code to it.

Comment: @2012rcampion, it only checks if the program's visible window exists. If that window is closed, the variable time is 0 and the new one will close after 15 minutes.

Comment: And if by "idle" you mean "not active", replace `If WinExist("title of the connection window")`  by `If !WinActive("title of the connection window")` in the above code.